# Where is the certificate of a TSA stored in XAdES-T?

Tags: xml, digital-signature, trusted-timestamp

In XAdES-T, the <EncapsulatedTimeStamp/>-element contains the TimeStampToken received from a TSA and not the entire TimeStampResp. But this TimeStampToken does not contain the certificate of the TSA (which can be found in the SignerInfo of the SignedData container).

Where am I supposed to store this certificate in the XAdES-document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While going over the [RFC 3161](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3161.txt) standard again, I found out that I mistook TimeStampToken for TSTInfo. TSTInfo does not contain the certificate, but TimeStampToken does.

Comment: What goes for the ``<EncapsulatedTimeStamp/>``? The ``TSTInfo`` or the ``TimeStampToken``?